# Removing object from PHP array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array of associative arrays with the following format:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
   { ["name"]=> "Steve Jobs"
     ["email"]=> "steve@gmail.com" }
}
```

I'm very new to PHP, but what I want to do is search for a specific email, and if found, delete that specific array (name & email pair) from the array (without leaving an empty space in the array where the removed object used to be).

I found this code here that searches for an entry but returns an array. How would I modify this to delete the found array?

```
function search($array, $key, $value)
{
    $results = array();

    if (is_array($array))
    {
        if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value)
            $results[] = $array;

        foreach ($array as $subarray)
            $results = array_merge($results, search($subarray, $key, $value));
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function delete_user(&$arr, $name){
    for($i = count($arr)-1; $i >= 0; $i--){
        if($arr[$i]["name"] == $name){
            unset($arr[$i]);
        }
    }
}
```

the `&$arr` tells PHP to pass the array by reference, so it can be modified from the function, otherwise, it'll be pass-by-value.

Comment: Yes I think this might work..although wouldn't I have to use `strcmp` to compare strings, or would `==` work too?

Comment: You can compare strings with `==` in PHP

Comment: I'm pretty sure this code won't work exactly right. If I have two results that are consecutive elements in the array, and you remove the first one, this will gloss over the second one.

Comment: How do you mean? I just tested it and it removed both elements even when there was a duplicate twice in a row.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) to remove an element and use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) or [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) method to search an element from an array.

```
unset($array[0]);
```

Sample from PHP manual (array_search)

```
function array_key_index(&$arr, $key) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach(array_keys($arr) as $k) {
        if($k == $key) return $i;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well they'll be more than 1 entry, say over 30 name, email pairs. I want to search for a specific one and delete it

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's a small problem with **[raser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/686557/raser)**'s answer. I tried to comment on it, but I can't since I don't have 50 reputation.

Let me know if you agree: `count($arr)` returns the number of elements in the array. He's using a decremental `for` loop, except the array's index starts at `0` and his loop ends before it reaches `0`, so the first element of the array is never searched. I believe the correct code would be something like:

```
function delete_user(&$arr, $name){
    for($i = count($arr) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--){
        if($arr[$i]["name"] == $name){
            unset($arr[$i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

just found array index, and

unset(array(key));

this will not showing that array

Comment: <?php
$array = array( 'Tires'=>100, 
'Oil'=>10, 'Spark Plugs'=>4 );


foreach($array as $key=>$value) {

echo 'Key= '.$key.'<br>';

echo 'Value= '.$value.'<br>';
}
?>

Comment: <?php
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
?>